# Visual Studio 2013 launches the wrong MVC Application

Tags: visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

This seems like a typical Microsoft bug.  I have a project that when I click launch despite the fact that it's set as the default project is launches a skeleton MVC app as opposed to the MVC app that I'm currently working on.

To fix the problem I have to close down Visual Studio completely and relaunch my solution.  I press f5 or just run the app and it works.

What I find interesting is this mysterious skeleton app which seems to be ASP.NET temporary files is the same port as my project.  This happens multiple times a day while developing this particular app on the particular port.  Does anybody know why Visual Studio 2013 is doing this?

Answer (score 2):

Okay so this is a Microsoft bug.  It turns out the project I'm working on does have identical names to another project that I was working on except in a different codeline.  Visual Studio gets all confused and launches the old app in cache instead of the app I'm working on.  The only way to fix this it appears it to manually change the port number for IIS Express.

For more information check this out.

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/786645/vs-launches-the-wrong-mvc-website-when-two-identically-named-solutions-are-open-at-the-same-time